# Is there any way to add a discriminator property to read data into a discriminated union object with Axios + Typescript?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, axios, discriminated-union

I want to read data from an API into a Typescript discriminated union object using an Axios client instance.
Below is a minimal example of what I thought would work but hasn't:

```
type UnionTypeA = {
  prop1: number;
  prop2: number;
  discriminator: "A";
}

// Within function or react component:

const client = axios.create();
const response = await client.get<UnionTypeA>('example/api/url');
```

The API Response is JSON of the form of the union type without the discriminator e.g. `{ prop1: 1, prop2: 2 }`.
I expected the value of `response` to be `{ prop1: 1, prop2: 2, discriminator: "A" }`, and the typescript compiler allows me to call on the discriminator property in code without errors, but at runtime upon running the above code the discriminator property doesn't get added to the response and is undefined, so I can't use it to discriminate values of this type from another in generic code.

Is there any way to achieve this adding of the discriminator literal on the client side upon fetching the data with Axios without altering the API response to include the discriminator property?

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can create a simple wrapper for that purpose. It may look like that, for example:

```ts
const getApiResultWithDiscriminator = async <
    T extends { discriminator: string }
>(url: string, discriminator: string): Promise<T | Error> => {
    const response = await client.get<T>(url);
    if (axios.isAxiosError(response)) throw new Error('error text')

    response.data.discriminator = discriminator;
    return response.data
}

const response = 
    await getApiResultWithDiscriminator<UnionTypeA>('example/api/url', 'a');
```

[playground link](https://tsplay.dev/mA7p1w)

Answer (score 0):

Agree with the answer from @aleksxor. Just want to add that a type or interface is used for "assertion" in the question, it is only existing at compile time for type checking. It is not going to alter the data in response (i.e. add a discriminator with value).